# AWS Glue - Development endpoint price for idle time

Tags: aws-glue

Is there any pricing charges for an AWS Glue - Developer Endpoint's idle time?  Say, I have a developer endpoint configured, and a job is run every day for 30 minutes.  Will the pricing be only for the 30 minutes duration every day or including the idle time for AWS Glue - Developer endpoint.

Thanks

Yuva

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://aws.amazon.com/glue/pricing/

> Development endpoints are optional, and billing applies only if you choose to interactively develop your ETL code. Development endpoints are charged based on the Data Processing Unit hours used for the time your development endpoints are provisioned.

So the answer is yes, you pay for the idle time.

> Development endpoint example: Now let’s consider that you provision a development endpoint to connect your notebook to interactively develop your ETL code. A development endpoint is provisioned with 5 DPUs. If you keep the development endpoint running for 24 minutes or 2/5th of an hour, you will be billed for 5 DPUs * 2/5 hour at $0.44 per DPU-Hour or $0.88.

Comment: Thanks, if am correct, we can use the development endpoints for our script testing with zeppelin (local laptop), and once if everything is fine, deploy/upload the code to a job schedule.

Comment: That's my understanding.

Comment: Thanks lfk.  Did some comparison and here is my findings:

Comment: AWS EMR Pricing:
A per-second rate for every second you use, with a one-minute minimum
The hourly rate depends on the instance type used (e.g. standard, high cpu, high memory, high storage, etc) 
The Amazon EMR price is in addition to the Amazon EC2 price (the price for the underlying servers) and Amazon EBS price (if attaching Amazon EBS volumes).

Comment: AWS Glue:
A simple monthly fee, above the AWS Glue Data Catalog free tier, for storing and accessing the metadata in the AWS Glue Data Catalog.
Additionally, you will pay an hourly rate, billed per second, for the ETL job (based on number of DPUs) and crawler run, with a 10-minute minimum for each.

Comment: I decided to stick with Spark on EMR because testing and development weren't as straightforward on Glue. You can't run and test your code locally (or on CI server) without sending it to Glue and paying for a dev endpoint.

Comment: In terms of cost, I'm not sure how they compare. Note that you can use Data Pipeline to run EMR jobs on clusters that are launched and terminated automatically

Comment: Agreed on both Glue Dev Endpoint cost, but if you see the EMR cost, there is a cost attached to the EC2 instance that its, running. but yeah, it all depends on specific use cases, trade-offs, etc.  FYI, I was able to set up a glue EMR using S3 as source, Redshift as my target for storing the cleansed data.  Also tried to connect the final data with AWS Quicksight for visualizations finally, which worked as well.

Comment: After testing successfully the Dev Endpoint, I had deleted the endpoint, and uploaded the code to a S3 bucket, created an Glue Job to run my code, residing in the S3 bucket. Thx

Comment: @Yuva when you say a 10 minute minimum for each run you mean if my jobs and crawlers run for only 3 mins avg I'm still getting charged 10 mins meaning I'm paying 7 minutes extra?