# Faster development turnaround time with AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

AWS Glue looks promising but I'm having a challenge with the development cycle time. If I edit PySpark scripts through the AWS console, it takes several minutes to run even on a minimal test dataset.  This makes it a challenge to iterate quickly if I have to wait 3-5 minutes just to see whether I called the right method on `glueContext` or understood a particular `DynamicFrame` behavior.

What techniques would allow me to iterate faster?

I suppose I could develop Spark code locally, and deploy it to Glue as an execution framework.  But if I need to test code with Glue-specific extensions, I am stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For development and testing scripts Glue has [Development Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint.html) which you can use with notebooks like Zeppelin installed either on a [local machine](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-local-notebook.html) or on [Amazon EC2 instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-EC2-notebook.html) (other options are 'REPL Shell' and 'PyCharm Professional').

Please don't forget to remove the endpoint when you are done with testing since [you pay for it even if it's idling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48224931/aws-glue-development-endpoint-price-for-idle-time).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I keep pyspark code in separate class file and glue code in another file. We use glue for reading and writing data only. We do test driven development using pytest in local machine. No need of dev endpoint or zeppelin. Once all syntactical or business logic specific bugs are fixed in pyspark, end-to-end testing is done using glue. We also wrote shell script, which uploads latest code to S3 bucket from which glue job is run.

1. https://github.com/fatangare/aws-glue-deploy-utility
2. https://github.com/fatangare/aws-python-shell-deploy

Comment: Yes, that's sort of where I was going - that will shorten the cycle time of the code you can test locally but you won't be able to run any Glue-specific code locally.